# How can i execute foreach loop on multidimensional loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array, which is consist of many arrays. So i want to execute foreach loop on it. I want to generate options from it.

### Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 201
            [first_name] => ayaz
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 212
            [first_name] => khalique
        )
)
```

### I have tried

```
 <?php foreach($UserDataEmail as $user){
            foreach($user as $val){?>
                <option value="<?=$val['user_id']?>" ><?=$val['first_name']?></option>
            <?php }
    }// end foreach ?>
```

But it does not work, can any one guide me where i'm wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the next `foreach` loop as you can access the values directly from there -

```
 <?php foreach($UserDataEmail as $user){ ?>
     <option value="<?=$user['user_id']?>" ><?=$user['first_name']?></option>
 <?php }// end foreach ?>
```